# No se ve la imagen y esta desacomodado el texto

Tags: python, bootstrap, django

tengo un problema, tengo unos posts y la imagen no se ve y el texto se sale del container.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del container:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 mt-5 p-0 post-container">
```

Edito:
Esto es lo que me sale en inspeccionar elemento-network:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo css:

```
    html, body {
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#auth-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

#main-navbar {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.0975);
}

.post-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


#user-posts #post-thumb {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Y este es el error que sale en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar tus estilos CSS a la pregunta y además una captura de que todo te carga bien en tu navegador para ello debes hacer click derecho y acceder **inspeccionar elemento** lugo acceder a la pestaña red y estando ahí recargas la ventana. Eso es útil para determinar que esta pasando con la carga de tu imagen.

Comment: @allexiusw ahi edite la pregunta con todo lo que dijiste en tu comentario anterior!

Comment: Estas utilizando static files para tus imagenes ya las definiste? y al llamarlas lo haces utilizando static en tus vistas? Como se explica en la documentación oficial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Tengo el STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIR, STATICFILES_FINDERS, MEDIA_ROOT y MEDIA_URL en el archivo settings, en urls puesto el static(y lo parametros que van adentro), en la consola me sale not found: /media/

Comment: Discutamolo en el chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107819/django creo que hay mucha información que verificar.

Comment: Seria importante que compartas la captura de tu post_card.html con el error de no estar haciendo referencia a los recursos estaticos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola te comparto la solución, sería bueno que actualices con el error en la view post_card.html para que la comunidad pueda saber más en que consiste tu error

Asi me queda el `post_card.html`:

```py
{% load static %}
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 mt-5 p-0 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded post-container">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="{% static "" %}{{ post.photo.url }}" >
    <p>{{ post.photo.url }}</p>

    <p class="ml-2 mt-0 mb-2">
        <p>{{ post.title }}</p> - <small>{{ post.created }}</small>
    </p>

    <p>
        <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

El problema se daba principalmente porque estabas utilizando `post.photos.url` y en tu modelo esta definido como `post.photo.url`.

Cabe tambien destacar que el problema del texto es porque como te lo sugirieron debias ponerlo en una etiqueta `p` ya que estabas utilizando `b`.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El error que muestra es el [404](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) por que el servidor dice que no encuentra el archivo solicitado.

Si quieres ocultar el texto puedes usar `overflow: hidden`.
O si lo que quieres es que se corte el texto en lineas formando un parrafo deberias probar con `word-wrap:word-break`.
Deberías poner una etiqueta `<p>` al texto.

```
.post-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
overflow:hidden
}
```